# wordpress upgrade has broken my permalinks

Tags: php, iis, permalinks

I have just upgraded my wordpress installation from  3.1 to 3.1.1 and my custom structure permalinks are now broken,

The permalinks were set to follow this procedure,

> /%category%/%postname%

however now they are just falling back to

> ?page_id=30

How can I fix this what has changed in 3.1.1 I wonder if it is a problem with my .htaccess file? Or maybe I am running on IIS?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some steps for you

a) Access you site through ftp and remove .htaccess file (possibly backup it)

b) Go to admin of your site (wordpress admin) and open permalink  settings form

c) set the first option to custom and put the value in text box

```
/%category%/%postname%
```

d) save changes and check you front-end for links

e) if proper links visible check one to view if they aren't returning 404

f) if you see 404 , put this line at the top of the .htaccess

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
```

hopefully this will this the issue

:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) with the `rewrite` option you will want to flush your WP Rewrite rules after an upgrade.  Adding this to your plugin or functions.php can help (tested with 3.4):

```
    // After an upgrade, flush rewrite rules
    function flush_rules_post_upgrade() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        if( is_object($wp_rewrite) )
            $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
    add_action('update_option_db_upgraded','flush_rules_post_upgrade');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your .htaccess is no more getting updated from admin.

> So try to update url re-writing code manually in .htacess.